# Why can't I use Sphere to scale glyphs?

Tags: c++, vtk

I have a point clouds dataset and I want to scale the size of a point according to its property value. I followed this example: https://vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Visualization/ScaleGlyphs#Download_and_Build_ScaleGlyphs. But when I built the project, an error occurred: abort() has been called:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zhbcf.png). I've tried CubeSource, ArrowSource, CylinderSource, they all worked out. I'm really confused why I can't use SphereSource.

I will be appreciated if anyone could help. Thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

```
void ScalePoints::draw() {

    //load data
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkXMLPolyDataReader> currentReader = readers[currentId];
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyData> polyData = currentReader->GetOutput();

    //set a scalar
    vtkDataArray* scalar = polyData->GetPointData()->GetArray("hh");
    int numPoints = scalar->GetNumberOfValues();  
    polyData->GetPointData()->SetScalars(scalar);

    //create spheres
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkSphereSource> SphereSource = vtkSmartPointer<vtkSphereSource>::New();
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkGlyph3D> glyph3D = vtkSmartPointer<vtkGlyph3D>::New();
    glyph3D->SetScaleModeToScaleByScalar();
    glyph3D->SetSourceConnection(SphereSource->GetOutputPort());
    glyph3D->SetInputData(polyData);
    glyph3D->SetScaleFactor(0.01);
    //glyph3D->SetRange(0.01, 0.05);
    glyph3D->Update();

    //visualize 
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper> sMapper = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper>::New();
    sMapper->SetInputConnection(glyph3D->GetOutputPort());
    actor->SetMapper(sMapper);
    actor->GetProperty()->SetOpacity(0.7);
    renderer->AddActor(actor);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a bug..
what happens if you do instead:

```cpp
    SphereSource->Update();
    glyph3D->SetSourceData(SphereSource->GetOutput());
```